# Populating new field with data from old field such that new field at fid was equal to old field at fid -1 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgsexpression

In QGIS there is a layer *'Layer'* with its attribute table:

```
fid   Oldfield      Newfield
1      cat          ----- 
2      horse        cat 
3      dog          horse 
4      swan         dog
```

I tried using the expression:

```
attribute(get_feature('Layer', 'fid', $id - 1), 'Oldfield')
```

but the result came out to be `NULL`. What is the expression to create the new field `"Newfield"`?

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression and make sure to set the `Output field type` to `Text (string)`:

```
attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer, $id-1), 'Oldfield')
```